# VBA Error Handling for when a file doesn't exist in the directory

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I've written some code to launch workbooks if they exist in a specific folder based on cell entry. I'm having trouble displaying an error message when the entry is blank and/or when it doesn't exist in the file. I've tried using *On Error GoTo MsgBox* but the MsgBox would show up even though the entry was correct.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'PART NUMBER DECLARATIONS
Dim part1 As Long
Dim part2 As Long

'Variable Assignments
part1 = 123
part2 = 234

If Target.Address = "$G$9" Then

varCellvalue = Range("G9").Value

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\USERX\Desktop\Test File\" & varCellvalue & ""

 ElseIF varCellvalue <> Range("G9").Value Then

MsgBox" Invalid Part Number"

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the error handling code you tried? Did you possibly forget an `Exit Sub` before the handler section?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using error handling, another approach would be to simply check if the file exists and then respond appropriately:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'PART NUMBER DECLARATIONS
   Dim part1 As Long
   Dim part2 As Long

   'Variable Assignments
   part1 = 123
   part2 = 234

   If Target.Address = "$G$9" Then
      varCellvalue = "C:\Users\USERX\Desktop\Test File\" & Range("G9").Value & ""

      If Dir(varCellvalue) <> "" Then
         Workbooks.Open varCellvalue
      Else
         MsgBox "The file does not exist"
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

I think this approach is cleaner and perhaps more intuitive.

Comment: Thank you, I agree this is a better approach. However, your code displays MsgBox no matter what you put in the cell and doesn't launch any workbooks. Not sure why.

Comment: Note that error handling (as I showed in my answer) is a much better approach. While you just test if the file exists, that doesn't mean that `Workbooks.Open` can open it without error. So with error handling you catch **all** errors that have the effect that the file cannot be opened, while your test just prevents the "file does not exists" error. If the file exists but you have no privileges to open it your code fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement error handling. Here is one …

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '… rest of your code

    On Error Goto ERR_FILE_OPEN
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\USERX\Desktop\Test File\" & varCellvalue & "")
    On Error Goto 0 'don't forget to re-enable error reporting

    '… rest of your code

    Exit Sub
ERR_FILE_OPEN:
    MsgBox "File '" & varCellvalue & "' could not be opened.", vbCritical
End Sub
```

For more information read: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

---

Note that

```
If Target.Address = "$G$9" Then
```

is not a very reliable method to test if the cell G9 was changed. Instead always use the intersect method to test if a range was changed:

```
If Not Intersect(Me.Range("G9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    varCellvalue = Me.Range("G9").Value
```

Answer (score -1):

There is many of approaches of implementing error detection, here are a couple of popular ones.

1. The Try-Catch approach

```
' The "Try" part
On Error Resume Next
...
On Error GoTo 0
' The "Catch" part
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
...
End If
```

2. The On error Goto  approach

```
on error goto Oops
..
..
..
Exit Sub
Oops:
    'handle error here
End Sub

For a comprehensive approach, refer to further reading "VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide." provided by PEH.
```

Comment: `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` will never be `True`. Your first example just hides all error messages between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`.